# Index error list out of range

Tags: python, csv, indexing, range

Edit: I think the problem Is to do with blank lines in the body of the csv file. Ive tried a number of fixes but to no avail. Its frustrating because this code was working originally Id appreciate if anyone has any ideas so that I can get on with my life :)

I had this code working. It would input from a csv file and output the specific columns to a text file. I was trying to make it only print the row if `row[32]` contained text. Since I started messing with it, its not working at all.

It now gives me the error `Index error: list out of range`. The csv file contains numerous columns and rows so it is definitely not out of range. I'm so googly eyed from looking at it that I can't see the wood from the trees anymore. I might have totally messed it up or it could just be something small.

```
import csv
import os

with open("raw.csv", "r") as f, open("txtfile.txt", "w") as output:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in r:
        output.write("{} --- {} --- {}\n".format(row[4], row[1], row[6]))

with open("txtfile.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(r)+"\r\n")
    print("Written successfully")

with open("raw.csv", "r") as f, open("txtfile.txt", "w") as output:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in r:
        if "Active" in row[0] and "Text1"in row[1] or "Text2" in row[1]   or "Burglary" in row[1]:
            output.write("{} - {} - {}\n".format(row[4], row[6], row[1])
```

Comment: When using `row[]`, the value inside the `[]` refers to a column header. So `row[6]` prints the values for each row in column 6, not the values of the 6th row in your file.

Comment: That's what I thought, and that part was working a few days ago

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed the problem. It was to do with blank lines so i added the words "in row and row[]" to the if statement. This had the affect of ignoring blank lines and thereby not giving me the index error.  Adding "and row[32] ensured it only printed rows where row[32] contains text

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as f, open("cops.txt", "w") as output:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in r:
        if "Active" in row and row[0] and row[32]:     
            output.write("{} - {} - {}".format(row[4], row[1], row[6])
            + "  {} \n \n".format(row[19]) + "  {} \n \n".format(row[32]) + "
            {}\n\n".format(row[13]) + "\n\n")
```